# Make TouchableOpacity not highlight element when starting to scroll [React Native]

Tags: javascript, react-native, listview, scroll, scrollview

`TouchableOpacity` makes things touchable, or as React Native says:

> A wrapper for making views respond properly to touches.

But using it inside a `ScrollView` or `ListView` results in highlighting when we (or at least I) do not want that.

These are three steps involved in scrolling down a `ListView` filled with elements:

- Touch an element
- Move finger up
- Release finger

Touching the element immediately results in a highlight animation. But in this case, we just want to scroll. We do not want to do anything with that element, be it highlighting or opening a detail view etc.

This does not happen all the time but most of the times on my Android device.

What is a proper way of handling this?

Comment: Out of interest, what's the use-case for wrapping a scroll-view in a touchable highlight?

Comment: That's not the case. We are wrapping a `TouchableOpacity` element **inside** a `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A scroll gesture should cancel the `TouchableOpacity` touch responder, but if you think the `TouchableOpacity` highlight is triggered to early, you can try tweaking the `delayPressIn` property.

Comment: Thank you. I did not consider the `TouchableWithoutFeedback` props. Now I set the `delayPressIn` to a very high number because I do not want that animation to appear when holding a button. It does not feel entirely right though. I think I am going to need a custom highlighting animation for tapping, holding and longPressing in the long run.

Comment: Thanks `delayPressIn` worked well, I set mine to `50` which seems appropriate for my swipe gesture.

Comment: Dude I love you so hard right now. I don't know why this prop. isn't documented. React-Native is a mess when it comes to documentation. Now I can stop using the buggy TouchableHighlight (which works really bad with borders and images)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `delayPressIn={1000}`, which will delay the animation until you press for 1 second.

**`delayPressIn`** property of `<TouchableOpacity>` delay in ms, from the start of the touch, before onPressIn is called.

Example to use :

```
<FlatList
  horizontal
  contentContainerStyle={{ paddingRight: 16 }}   // this set the padding to last item
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}         // hide the scroller
  data={results}
  keyExtractor={(result) => result.data.id}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        delayPressIn={1000}         // delay animation for 1 second
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ResultsShow')}
      >
        <ResultsDetail result={item.data} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }}
/>;
```

You can find more about this [Here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#delaypressin).

Answer (score 1):

`delayPressIn` doesn't have the desired effect because, if the user taps fast enough, no effect is shown.

The right solution is use Pressable, which correctly avoids firing `onPress` when the user appears to be scrolling, and adding an opacity animation, like this:

```
const PressableWithAnimation = React.memo((props) => {
  const animated = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;

  const handlePress = () => {
    animated.setValue(0.4);
    Animated.timing(animated, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 400,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start()
    if (props.onPress) props.onPress();
  };

  return (
    <Pressable onPress={handlePress}>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.button, { opacity: animated }]}>
        {props.children}
      </Animated.View>
    </Pressable>
  );
});
```

You can compare all of the implementations I tried here: https://snack.expo.dev/@pickleheadsian/button-tests-in-scrollview