# Disable TouchableOpacity highlighting when scrolling

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, touchableopacity

I want to disable highlighting of TouchableOpacity when scrolling inside of FlatList or ScrollView. onPress did not trigger when scrolling, it is just the highlighting effect that got triggered.

I've tried delayPressIn but it only delay the onPress time not the highlighting effect.

Answer (score 8):

That's a bit late but setting `delayPressIn={ 50 }` to your `touchableOpacity` component should fix your issue.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37642488/9360334